# php mysql search engine which method is more efficient FULLTEXT or LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

After reading lot of articles got confused.

I have a search engine that searches library books.
What is the best method for PHP/MySQL search engine `FULLTEXT SEARCH` OR `LIKE WILDCARDS %%`. Also the search algorithm.

In `FULLTEXT SEARCH` can I split the words to array like in `LIKE` method? Is it possible to search for a specific word instead of exact phrase match.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Like wilcard i.e. %LIKE% is best for searching text as it matches the search keyword in any string that contains the search keyword. It does not has to be exact match. That's why the search result will return multiple book titles containing the search KEYWORD to the user.

%KEYWORD% means there might be text before or after the search keyword in the matching title.

Comment: what about full text search is there way we can use full text search function as like do @gigabit

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/6937928/gigabit

Comment: %LIKE% will work for matching full text too. For example, your full search string is "HOW TO LEARN" and assume, there are 3 titles in the db named "HOW TO LEARN PHP","COMPLETE GUIDE ABOUT HOW TO LEARN PHP" and "CHECK HOW TO LEARN JAVA"..All these titles will be returned as search result if you use %LIKE% wild card.

Comment: @gigabit fulltext search is sg different :)

Comment: so tell me what i use LIKE or Full Text searh @gigabit

Comment: so tell me what i use LIKE or Full Text search  @Shadow

Comment: If you have only a small amount of data, then it does not really matter which one you use. If you have lot of data, then you need to go with fulltext search, possibly using an external fulltext plugin, such as sphynx.